# How can I create a more fine grained web socket in JSF?

Tags: jsf, omnifaces

In my JSF application I'm trying to use web sockets to push updates from backend to frontend. The backend publishes messages on an ActiveMQ topic which I'm listening to (on @ApplicationScoped level).

I've got two channels which are created by injecting on a @WebListener, like this:

```java
@Inject
    public void setControllerEventChannel(@Push(channel = "controllerEventChannel") PushContext controllerEventChannel) {
        this.controllerEventChannel = controllerEventChannel;
    }

    @Inject
    public void setGroupEventChannel(@Push(channel = "groupEventChannel") PushContext groupEventChannel) {
        this.groupEventChannel = groupEventChannel;
    }
```

```xml
<o:socket channel="controllerEventChannel" onmessage="onMessage" />

<h:commandScript name="onMessage" actionListener="#{backingBean.controllerChannelCallback()}"
                             process="@this" update="@none"/>
```

The challenge is, I've got many controllers and many groups. How do I push messages on these channels such that all opened views don't receive all callbacks? The views are controller or group specific. My current solution is filtering events in the actionListener method and it's, in a word, terrible.

I *wish* I could create channels dynamically, but I don't there's a way to do that in JakartaEE?

Comment: Have you considered using the `user` attribute? Then you just push to all users associated with a certain channel.

Comment: I've thought about it, but that would require application scoped knowledge regarding which users could access which resources and I'd like to avoid that. Both for caching and security reasons.

I'm currently attempting to come at this from another angle: inject PushContext into the view scoped beans and subscribe temporarily from there. I'm using your OmniFaces ViewScoped with PreDestroy to unsubscribe. It seems to be doing the trick!

Comment: The OmniFaces solution works perfectly! I was attacking the problem from the wrong side.

Answer (score 1):

For this you can use the `user` attribute,

```xml
<o:socket channel="some" user="#{user.id}">
```

with

```java
Collection<Long> recipientUserIds = recipientGroup.getUserIds();
someChannel.send(message, recipientUserIds);
```

Or even

```xml
<o:socket channel="some" user="#{user.group.id}">
```

with

```java
someChannel.send(message, recipientGroup.getId());
```